# KSOAP2 calling asynchronous webservice got illegalArgumentException

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm calling an asynchronous web service (the server does not return anything) using KSOAP2.
The web service call is already succeed, i can see that from the server, but the HttpTransportSE.call throws an exception and crashed the app.

My code is:

```
envelope.bodyOut = soap;
    envelope.dotNet = false;
    MarshalDouble md = new MarshalDouble();
    md.register(envelope);


        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(null, envelope);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and the error log is:

```
01-04 17:25:05.930: E/Trace(17787): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-04 17:25:06.145: E/SensorManager(17787): thread start
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: size <= 0
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.<init>(BufferedInputStream.java:94)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:219)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:114)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at com.oracle.bpm.mobile.fragment.PSIRFragment.callBPMProcessAcceleratorAdapter(PSIRFragment.java:447)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at com.oracle.bpm.mobile.fragment.PSIRFragment.access$1(PSIRFragment.java:368)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at com.oracle.bpm.mobile.fragment.PSIRFragment$CallPSIRMobileAdapterTask.doInBackground(PSIRFragment.java:364)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at com.oracle.bpm.mobile.fragment.PSIRFragment$CallPSIRMobileAdapterTask.doInBackground(PSIRFragment.java:1)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-04 17:25:19.145: E/AndroidRuntime(17787):    ... 5 more
```

Does anybody knows why? How can i call an asynchronous web service using ksoap?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I checked code of HttpTransportSE.java and it seems there isn't a way to prevent it from getting the response. So I have to change my web service to synchronous and return something like OK to fix this problem. Hope KSOAP2 will fix this.